# Removing specific sequences from a string

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I just started python and I have a quick question about strings. Say I have a string that contains both an open and closed bracket (with characters in it) that looks something like this:

`result = 10['1', '0']0`

What I would like to know is how I can manipulate the string to make it look like this:

`result = 100`

Comment: Can you explain that whats the logic behind this convert?

Comment: I just to know how I can remove a substring from string that is identifiable with square brackets.

Comment: So you can use @Avinash's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to replace characters present inside the square brackets (*including brackets*) with an empty string .

```
In [8]: result = "10['1', '0']0"

In [9]: re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', '', result)
Out[9]: '100'
```

Comment: Its not working me for some reason I should of specified that I'm using python 2.7.9

Comment: Simplest is actually `r'\[.*?\]'`, a **non-greedy** match -- equivalent to the RE pattern in this response but shorter and a tad more readable.